# Javascript link in theme.info not working Drupal 7

Tags: 7, javascript, uri

Why is my jquery.js file not found when I use this code in my theme.info?

Im using drupal 7.

```
scripts[] = js/jquery.js
```

I got this code from the drupal page and I'm 100% sure its the right path.
what did i do wrong here?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Explaining how to properly replace Drupal's jQuery in a module would require a copy of [jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update), all it's issues, explanations, comments etc. I honestly don't think it is possible in Q&A format. Why not to just **use** that module?

Comment: Have to agree with @Mołot, jQuery Update module is the way to go here. You could always use `hook_js_alter()` and just unceremoniously overwrite the path to core's version of that file, but the jQuery Update module has already done all of the hard thinking for you about compatibility with existing modules and core

Comment: or if it not an update of jquery and any custom code is written then change the file name.. and if any changes made to theme.info then drupal cache needs to be clear..

Comment: oh yeah good idea gonna clear the cache :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your cache. I think it may work for you.